# display a histogram with very non-uniform bin widths

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

Here is the histogram
[image]

To generate this plot, I did:

```
bins = np.array([0.03, 0.3, 2, 100])
plt.hist(m, bins = bins, weights=np.zeros_like(m) + 1. / m.size)
```

However, as you noticed, I want to plot the histogram of the relative frequency of each data point with only 3 bins that have different sizes:

bin1 = 0.03 -> 0.3

bin2 = 0.3 -> 2

bin3 = 2 -> 100

The histogram looks ugly since the size of the last bin is extremely large relative to the other bins. How can I fix the histogram? I want to change the width of the bins but I do not want to change the range of each bin.

Comment: but then it's not a histogram anymore, is it?

Comment: @cel, no, it can be a `bar graph`.

Comment: Well, have you tried plotting a bar graph? You get the number of counts in each bin from `np.histogram`, so the implementation should be straight forward.

Comment: @cel - yes I tried it. I still didn't figure out a way to change the numbers on the xaxis .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As @cel pointed out, this is no longer a histogram, but you can do what you are asking using `plt.bar` and `np.histogram`. You then just need to set the `xticklabels` to a string describing the bin edges. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bins = [0.03,0.3,2,100] # your bins
data = [0.04,0.07,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.8,1,1.5,4,5,7,8,43,45,54,56,99] # random data

hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(data,bins) # make the histogram

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

# Plot the histogram heights against integers on the x axis
ax.bar(range(len(hist)),hist,width=1) 

# Set the ticks to the middle of the bars
ax.set_xticks([0.5+i for i,j in enumerate(hist)])

# Set the xticklabels to a string that tells us what the bin edges were
ax.set_xticklabels(['{} - {}'.format(bins[i],bins[i+1]) for i,j in enumerate(hist)])

plt.show()
```

[image]

**EDIT**

If you update to `matplotlib v1.5.0`, you will find that `bar` now takes a kwarg `tick_label`, which can make this plotting even easier ([see here](http://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html#plot-bar-and-barh-with-labels)):

```
hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(data,bins)

ax.bar(range(len(hist)),hist,width=1,align='center',tick_label=
        ['{} - {}'.format(bins[i],bins[i+1]) for i,j in enumerate(hist)])
```

Comment: when I do this I get two plots instead of one and the text isn't centered edit: the updated version works better, I still get two plots

Comment: Dear, there is no need for adding 0.5 for setting xticks anymore. Maybe due to change in matplotlib.

Comment: @saurabheights yes, you'll notice in the edit to my answer above that's accounted for already

Answer (score 2):

If your actual values of the bins are not important but you want to have a histogram of values of completely different orders of magnitude, you can use a logarithmic scaling along the x axis. This here gives you bars with equal widths

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [0.04,0.07,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.8,1,1.5,4,5,7,8,43,45,54,56,99]

plt.hist(data,bins=10**np.linspace(-2,2,5)) 
plt.xscale('log')

plt.show()
```

When you have to use your bin values you can do

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [0.04,0.07,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.8,1,1.5,4,5,7,8,43,45,54,56,99]
bins = [0.03,0.3,2,100] 

plt.hist(data,bins=bins) 
plt.xscale('log')

plt.show()
```

However, in this case the widths are not perfectly equal but still readable. If the widths must be equal and you have to use your bins I recommend @tom's solution.